# Arredondando números no Android

Tags: java, android, number-format

Estou querendo formatar numeração para apenas duas casas decimais depois da vírgula, estou usando a seguinte lina de código

`NumberFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("0.00");`

Mas a API mínima da minha aplicação é a 15 e ele esta pedindo a 24 para usar essa classe, alguém sabe alguma outra maneira de arredondar e formatar numeração?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você provavelmente está usando a classe `android.icu.text.NumberFormat` que é da API 24. Vá nas importações e troque para `java.text.NumberFormat`. O memo para o `DecimalFormat`: `java.text.DecimalFormat`.

Comment: Cara, Muito obrigado, que desatenção a minha, obrigado mesmo!!